# Is email address domain always the tenant domain in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm working on desktop software for administrators that uses the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK.

The software authenticates with email address and password.

When using Microsoft Graph SDK, TenantID or name is required. This is appears to be the contoso.onmicrosoft.com domain name that appears on the user's email address used to login to Office 365.

Is this always this domain? Are there cases where the login email domain is not the tenant name? Is it possible for an email address to be associated with more than one tenant? and if so, how do I check?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to provide the tenant if the Application Registration has been setup to only work for a single tenant, or if you are using a OAuth flow that requires it.  For desktop applications you can use "Interactive flow" and that does not need the tenant.  You can set it up like this,

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .Build();

InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#interactive-provider

This approach uses what is called the "common" authorization endpoint and it will figure out what tenant the user is based on their email address.

The tenant identifier can either be the {something}.onmicrosoft.com or it can be the corresponding GUID.  Organizations can associate custom domains with O365 tenants and these domains will also usually get mapped to the correct tenant.  If you make a call here:

```
https://login.windows.net/{someTenantName}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

You will get back a response that contains the `authorization_endpoint` that contains the GUID version of the tenant. That is one way to do the conversion yourself if necessary.

Comment: My difficulty is that I need the users login details, as I also have to use the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client SDK (Sharepoint CSOM) within the application.

Comment: Once you are signed in with Graph you can use the `/me` to retrieve the user's email address.  Does that help with your CSOM login?